# Can I limit the scope of ntop to only monitor a specific connection?

Tags: networking, centos, mysql, traffic, ntop

I need to be able to track client data usage between their VM and an S3 compatible object storage bucket (accessed via https).  I've installed `ntopng` community edition on the VM and right now it's dumping all it's data into a MySQL database.

I've noticed that the overhead of `ntopng` is not inconsequential, and these are not resource rich VM's, so I'd like to lessen it's memory/resource footprint if I can.  I'm ONLY interested in the connection described above, so is there a way to apply a filter to only track connections from a certain origin rather than tracking ALL traffic?

I'm actually only interested in the INBOUND traffic as well, as *uploads* are not billable, so I've already set the `--capture-direction=1` flag to only track `RX` traffic (from Bucket to VM).

I'm assuming that the web server component is either idle or disabled as I have not set any values for those params.  Or do I need to specifically disable them somehow? Lastly, I've disabled all DNS features.

Here is my current configuration at `/etc/ntopng/ntopng.conf`...

```
# ntopng Configuration
--community
-G=/run/ntopng.pid
-e=
-i=eth0
-n=3
--capture-direction=1
-N=myhost.tld
-F=mysql;/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;ntop;flows;user;pass
```

Alternatively, is there a better and/or lighter weight method of achieving what I need?  My goal is simply at the end of the month to know that Acme Co's VM used n GB of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better method for achieving my goal of tallying traffic from a specific IP. It's possible to do this using `iptables/nftables` which is already running in the kernel and already capable of incrementing both packet and byte totals.  It's a slightly more complicated configuration but worth it for the much lower overhead and simplicity.

[Where are nftables counters logged/stored, and how long do they persist?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1018654/where-are-nftables-counters-logged-stored-and-how-long-do-they-persist)